# How would you click all texts on a page with Xpath - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, this won't be a long description, but I am trying to have xpath click on all of the elements (more specifically text elements) that are on a page. I really don't know where to start, and all of the other questions on clicking everything on a page is based on a class, not a text using xpath.
Here is some of my code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='sample']").click()
```

I really don't know how I would go about to make it click all of the "sample" texts throughout the whole page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: What is an element contains text but is not clickable? In this case you will get exception. Can you clarify your question please? Clicking on all elements containing specific text? What is the sense of it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's say that you have lots of Divs or spans that contains text. Let's figure out Divs :

```
<div class="some class name" visibility ="visible" some other attribute> Text here </div>
```

Now when you go to developer mode(F12) in elements section and if you do this `//div[contains(@class,'some class name')]` and if there are more than 1 entry then you can store all of them in a list just like below :

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,'some class name')]')
```

this will give you a list of divs web element.

```
div_list  = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,'some class name')]')
```

Now you have a python list and you can manipulate this list as per your requirement.

```
for div_text in div_list:
   print(div_text.text)
```

Same way you can try for span or different web elements.

Comment: great! that fixed my first problem, but now i have encountered another... here it is... I am trying to click this "Place order" button, but it is unable to find the element. here is a screenshot of what I am trying to press: the highlighted code is what the "Place order" button is, but everything under that is unidentifiable for some reason. I have tried the class, the id, and the xpath text, but the xpath failed, due to other "Place order" texts being on the same page. any idea?
here's the photo of the code, the highlighted area is the "place order" button:
https://imgur.com/a/gzjZOxC

Comment: @MysteryPlayer12 : So you are saying that there are more than 1 element with `Place order` text ? if yes, and from the shared pic I can give you one xpath to try it out and that would be this `//button[@id='ember1164' and contains(text(),'Place order')]`. try this one and let me know if it works.

Comment: it seems as though it should work, but on Microsoft (I am trying to do this on Microsoft), they change the 'ember1164' thing every time you inspect the element, even without refreshing the page. The only way that I have thought around this problem is by having it find the "Place order" button (still using xpath text) in a certain part of the page, or just have it press all of the buttons that have "Place order" in it, since there is only 1 button that has "Place order" in it, which is obviously, the place your order button.

Comment: @MysteryPlayer12 : if that is the case then you can narrow down the numeric part from in `//button[contains(@id,'ember') and contains (text(),'Place order')]`

Comment: hmmm... the ember can range from 10 to 2000, so that method will not work. I think this brings us back to the idea of searching for the "Place order" text in a certain area of the page, clicking that instead of the regular texts. Only problem, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: any idea @cruisepandey?

Comment: How many "Place order" button do you see when you are on the web page ? Without doing scroll down.. if they are more in numbers then either we have to find out the unique locator or put everything in a list and then try to interact with the desire element in a loop.

Comment: There are from what I can see, 3 "Place order" texts on the page...

Comment: Can you try to write a locator with all of them. and use find elements instead. and probably use the index to click on it. Make sure that the desired element should be in selenium view port.

Comment: mhm... ok I will try. I am unsure on how to do so, but I will try.

Comment: @MysteryPlayer12 : this ticket looks like little old. has this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use that xpath to define an array of elements instead, like this:

```
my_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='sample']")
for element in my_elements:
    element.click();
```

That loop may not work as is (you could maybe add a wait for `element`) but that's the idea.